# Offline cache in Flex mobile application

Tags: .net, web-services, apache-flex, caching, mobile

I am creating a mail application in Flex mobile. How can I implement an offline cache feature in my Flex mobile application?

I need offline caching for mail which comes in to the user's Inbox, so if the user has no connection,  they can read previous/old email messages which were cached when they previously connected.

Is this possible from the Flex side?  If so, how?  If not, then what is a solution or what could I do for that.

On the server side i am using .net for getting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible (simple) solution is to use `SharedObject`:

```
public void cacheIncomingMail(message:EmailMessage):void {
  var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mobileMail");
  var cachedMessages:Array = so.data.messages;
  //Decide whether to remove anything from the array
  cachedMessages.push(message);
  so.data.messages = cachedMessages;
}
```

Be aware that this solution can dump a LOT of data into the SharedObject; [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) suggests that you use `SharedObject` for "limited amounts of data"

An alternative is to use the `File` [class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html):

```
public void cacheIncomingMail(message:EmailMessage):void {
  var dataFolder:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
  var desiredFilename:String = makeFilenameFromEmail(message);
  var mailStorageFile:File = dataFolder.resolvePath(desiredFilename);
  var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
  fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
  fileStream.writeUTF(message.toXML());
  fileStream.close();
}
```